# 1 IP and multiple domains?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, iis, domain-name

I have IIS7.5 and have multiple IP's, all which are in use.

I want to have another domain name added to a primary IP Address (which is in use). Is this possible? I however DO NOT want that domain name to clash with what is already hosted in that IP Address (its another website so basically I want 2 different websites on 1 IP Address)

is this possible? if so - how?

thanks

Comment: It's called *virtual hosts*.

Comment: thanks. so how do I set one up?

Comment: I don't have any experience with IIS, so I can't say anything more helpful. Just wanted to let you know what to google for.

Comment: This is better on ServerFault and may be moved there.  Please do not cross post.  However, there are likely several answer there already as this is pretty basic.  As suggested, Google Virtual Hosts to get started. Microsoft has many excellent TechNet articles as well

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816576/en-us

See step 5.c you should add as many host header names for the site as you want. Or only one, for example:

For one site:

```
www.mydomain.com
mydomain.com
192.168.0.3
```

For another site:

```
www.someotherdomain.com
someotherdomain.com
```

That way, typing any of the above in a browser will take you to one site or the other, and both will be on the same IP.

You can add the IP address itself as a host header name as I did in the first site.

Of course, DNS servers should match so everything works.